# Make bash script print set -x output in BOLD but output as normal text

Tags: bash, syntax-highlighting

I wish every command in my .sh to be printed in **bold,** but the *output* generated by the commands to not be bold.

(So that I can clearly see what the script does -- there is a lot of output).

Testcase:

```
> cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo foo

> ./foo.sh
+ echo foo
foo
```

(I want the `+ echo foo` in bold, and the `foo` normal, without manually specifying escape sequences, which would get ugly with many commands).

I am aware of how to output bold text using `echo` or `printf` with terminal escape sequences; but how can I affect how the `set -x` output is formatted?

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: Read about `PS2` `PS3` `PS4` variabels in bash manual Then connect that with the duplicate. Still, I do not believe it's possible to reset the flags back, as `PS4` is printed only at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to parse the output as it comes.

```
$ ./foo.sh 2> >(sed "/+ .*/s//$(tput bold)&$(tput sr0)/")
```

You could set `PS4` to contain `tput bold`, but there is no command to be executed *after* the `set -x` is printed, so there is no way to reset the behavior back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to apply bold per-command in the end:

```
BOLD='\033[1m'
RESET='\033[0m'

bold() { 
    printf '${BOLD}%s${RESET}\n' "$*"
    "$@"
}

bold ls
```

Also `{ tput bold; printf '%s\n' "$*"; tput sgr0; "$@"; }` works.